# A redundant(?) function in the definition of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The definition of a random variable which I learned is as following (Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference*)

> In defining a random variable,
>   we have also defined a new sample space (the range of the random variable).
>   We must now check formally that our probability function,
>   which is defined on the original sample space,
>   can be used for the random variable.
>
> Suppose we have a sample space
>   $$S=\{s_1, ..., s_n\}$$
>   wich a probability function $P$ and we define a random variable $X$ with range $\mathcal{X}=\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$.
>   We can define a probability function $P_X$ on $\mathcal{X}$ in the following way.
>   We will observe $X=x_i$ if and only if the outcome of the random experiment is an $s_j\in S$
>   such that $X(s_j)=x_i$.
>   Thus,
>   $$P_X(X=x_i)=P(\{s_j\in S:X(s_j)=x_i\}).$$

Let me give an example.
Let's toss a coin twice.
Then

$S=\{\text{HH}，\text{HT}，\text{TH}，\text{TT}\}$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{B} &=& \{\emptyset, \\
&& \{\text{HH}\}, \{\text{HT}\}, \{\text{TH}\}, \{\text{TT}\},\\
&& \{\text{HH}, \text{HT}\}, \{\text{HH}, \text{TH}\}, \{\text{HH}, \text{TT}\}, \{\text{HT}, \text{TH}\}, \{\text{HT}, \text{TT}\}, \{\text{TH}, \text{TT}\}, \\
&& \{\text{HH}, \text{HT}, \text{TH}\}, \{\text{HH}, \text{HT}, \text{TT}\}, \{\text{HH}, \text{TH}, \text{TT}\}, \{\text{HT}, \text{TH}, \text{TT}\},\\
&& S\}.
\end{eqnarray*}

$P:\mathcal{B}\to \Bbb{R}$,
$P(\emptyset)=0, P(\{\text{HH}\})=\frac{1}{4}, P(\{\text{HH}, \text{HT}\})=\frac{2}{4}, ..., P(S)=1$.

$X:S\to \Bbb{R}$,
the number of heads.
That is,
$X(\text{HH})=2, X(\text{HT})=1=X(\text{TH}), X(\text{TT})=0$.

$S_{\text{new}}=\mathcal{X}=\text{image of }X=\{0, 1, 2\}$.

$\mathcal{B}_{\text{new}}=\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,2\}, \{1,2\}, \{0,1,2\}\}$.

$P_{X}:\mathcal{B}_{\text{new}}\to \Bbb{R}$.

$P_X(X=1)\stackrel{\text{def.}}{=}P(\{s\in S\mid X(s)=1\})
=P(\{\text{HT}, \text{TH}\})=\frac{2}{4}$.

**Question:**
Why we need to define $\mathcal{X}$ and the other one probability function $P_X$?
That is, 
why don't we just define the notation $P(X=1)$ by $P(\{s\in S\mid X(s)=1\})$?

Comment: Here $P_X (\{1\})=P(X=1)$. The notation  $P_X (X=1)$ is not okay.

Comment: If $X:S\to\mathbb R$, the probability measure $P_X$ is defined on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, not only on your $\mathcal{B}_{\text{new}}$, for example, $$P_X([0.5,4])=P(.5\leqslant X\leqslant 4)=P(X=1)+P(X=2)=P(\{HH,HT,TH\})=\tfrac34$$

Comment: @drhab It should be written $P_X(\{1\})$ in rigorous. But I think that $P_X(X=1)$ is their convention. See the text which I quoted.

Comment: I am not blaming you of course, but in my view (and definitely lots of others) this convention is confusing and needless.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your comment. But I don't understand why you define $P_X$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
I just follows the definition of my textbook.

A probability measure $P$ on a $\sigma$-field of subsets $\mathcal{A}$ of a set $S$ is a real-valued function having domain $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying...
(Definition 2 in Ch.1 in Stone's Introduction to Probability Theory.)

We define for a given finite sample space $S$, 
$\mathcal{B}=\{\text{all subsets of }S, \text{ including }S\text{ itself}\}$.
(Example 1.2.2 in Casella & Berger's Statistical Inference.)

Comment: @drhab I can't agree with you more.
In our opinion, even the notation $P(X=1)$ is not rigorous.
I thought that there are many unrigorous notation when I learned probability theory first time. (The textbook I choosed is also a reason.)
Some book even define a notion by casual description.
Could you please give me more reference (the textbook you used) which is rigorous? Thanks!

Comment: There are two probability measures here, the probability $P$ defined on the sigma-algebra on $S$ and, as mentioned in my first comment, the probability $P_X$ defined on the sigma-algebra on $\mathbb R$. Since $\{X=1\}$ is a subset of $S$, not of $\mathbb R$, $P(\{X=1\})$ and $P_X(\{1\})$ both make sense (and they coincide) but $P_X(X=1)$ is absurd. Note that your last comment to drhab is rather disquieting, and muddies the waters without necessity, since the notation $P(X=1)$ is perfectly rigorous. Finally, one can make some reproaches to Casella-Berger about their notational choices...

Comment: @Did Hello. I read these comments today. I figure out what you were saying and where the problem was. Could you please suggest a probability and statistic book which uses rigorous notations and definitions? Thanks.

Comment: Durrett (choose the elementary textbook).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in a lot of situations we want to look at the probability distribution of the random variable and forget about the original state space.

Example : $S_1$ is two distinguished coins. $X$ is a random variable on $S_1$ defined this way: $X(HH) = 0, X(HT) = X(TH)=1, X(TT)=2$.

$S_2$ is a 8-sided dice. $Y$ is the randon variable on $S_2$ defined this way : $Y(1)=Y(5)=0, Y(2)=Y(4)=Y(6)=Y(8)=1, Y(3)=Y(7)=2$.

$X$ and $Y$ are a priori different random variables, not even defined in the same probability space, but after taking a closer look, we see that they have the same range $\mathcal{X} = \{0,1,2\}$ and that $P_X=P_Y$. We say that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.